# Nginx fastcgi cache in different location block

Tags: linux, nginx, cache, fastcgi

I am trying to cache different location with different cache keyzone but it is not working. Cache is only working for the root "/" location.

If I turn off the cache for location "/" then still it does not work for other location.

Http block:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /webcache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:100m max_size=1000m inactive=45m use_temp_path=off;
fastcgi_cache_path /webcache/extreme levels=1:2 keys_zone=extreme:100m max_size=10400m inactive=99999m use_temp_path=off;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

Server block:

```
location ~* "^/(20[0-1][0-8]/)" {              
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_cache extreme;
        fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
        fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
        fastcgi_cache_lock on;
        fastcgi_cache_lock_age 5s;
        fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout 5s;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 301 8760h;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 500 502 10s;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 403 404 10s;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;

}

location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}


     location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
    fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
    fastcgi_cache microcache;
    fastcgi_cache_min_uses 1;
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_cache_lock on;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_age 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout 5s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 302 301 1m;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 500 502 10s;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 403 404 10s;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
    fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;


        }
```

Comment: Do all of these `/2xxx/...` URIs get handled by `/index.php`?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes everything is handled by index.php

Comment: Is there any way supported by nginx to have different cache zone for different locations?  I want this to work so much but I failed to find a solution. For /2xxxx/  I tried adding double slash in index.php "try_files $uri $uri/ //index.php?$args;"  and then created another location for .php like this "location ~ //index\.php$ {"   but then page does not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI `/index.php` is processed by the last `location` block, so uses the `microcache` zone.

The URI `/2000/` is first rewritten to `/index.php` and then processed by the last `location` block, so uses the `microcache` zone.

To use an alternative zone, you could avoid rewriting the URI, and instead hardwire the fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME variable to `$document_root/index.php`, as all URIs matching that pattern are sent to `index.php` anyway.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/20[0-1][0-8]/ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    ...
    fastcgi_cache extreme;
    ...
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/opt/remi/php56/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    ...
    fastcgi_cache microcache;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. I am really sorry again, I am away from computer now. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: Hey it works =D  I had to remove quotes "^/20[0-1][0-8]/"  and then it started working. Strange but it works now.

Comment: hey Richard, sorry for asking one more question. As I can see my page is showing X-Cache HIT status. But still all my images, CSS, JS on that page is still being requested from backend.  How can I cache whole page with all its content?